# Delete the half inserted datatable if a power failure or user closes page by mistake, updated only the datatable if the full field has data

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a DataTable with ten fields and five of the fields will get data **inserted** from one interface and the rest five fields will get **updated** from another interface....The problem is if there is a power failure or the user closes the second interface by mistake the first five fields gets inserted but the next five will not get updated as when we load the page again the transaction number will change.....Is there any method that we can delete the first five rows unless we have updated the all ten fields........Its difficult to understand...please try to understand this and help me out

Answer (score 1):

Read up on TRANSACTIONS.

There is no need to delete if you wrap the insert into a transaction. Unless it is commited, it will be rolled back on disconnect / Restart.

This is Database fundamental stuff for beginners - so you should read up on it.

Comment: Can you please send me a link..... I am a beginner and i am hearing transaction for the first time ...

Comment: http://www.google.com/, books online - i.e. the documentation you can find ON YOUR COMPUTER also work. And as a beginner: amazon.com, grab a book. Read it.